# MyBatis to XML or CSV

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

Background

We have a list of tables in a database, we want to read them through select statements, then turn the result into csv files

Problem

I could use mybatis to load data from tableA then map it to a resultMap A, then using openCSV to save it as a csv file.

but I am seeking a generic way, which I only need to specify

```
<sql> select * from tableA </sql>
<csvFile> A.csv </csvFile>
<mapping> Table.1stName = CSV.firstName </Mapping>
<mapping> Table.2ndName = CSV.secondName </Mapping>
........
```

in my config.xml, and my program should be able to run the sql select
then map the resultset to a generic resutMap in mybatis? or turn
the results into xml or csv or any string format?

then I can composing the csv file using the mapping in my config

the key question is how to let the mybatis return a more generic format 
of the resultset, rather than map it to a specific object.

Comment: Does your database not have an export feature for that? What's the use case?

Comment: Honestly, the problem is easy enough, since you only need basic JDBC for that. I would probably add Spring into the mix to make it a little bit easier, but effectivly, you could only write the query (without *, but explicit list of columns) and read it, writing the fields (by index) into a csv. As ftr already mentioned, most databases should allow an export anyway, but the code for this sould be simple with JDBC alone, I wouldn't use MyBatis for that.

Comment: You could use spring batch which does have inbuilt mybatis db reader and writer to write as csv file. You can bringup the application in an hour or 2.

Answer (score 1):

@FlorianSchaetz indeed for low level parsing Spring JDBC comes in handy. Mybatis is a ORM, I didn't need to map the object. no need to using Mybatis. Finally the implementation is simple, Paring the XML using JAXB, then excute the sql using Spring JDBC, which returns a resultset, then according to the mapping names. extract data from the dataset, them amp to the right csv file field.